# CartoDB, problem with infowindows

Tags: carto

When I share my CartoDB-map, in other words,  use the link to my map, I can't get the info windows to appear. It says "there has been an error..." Why? How can i fix this?

Comment: Could you share with us the visualization for which this is happening? This error happens to appear sometimes when there's some problem with the internet connection and is just an temporal trouble, but please, let us know so we could check. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're connected to the Internet behind a proxy/firewall, it's probable that the infowindow requests are being blocked. In these cases, I recommend you to access your visualization by using HTTPS instead of HTTP, which usually solves the issue.